# How to get all _id values from a collection and store them in arraylist using MorphiaQuery in Java Play

Tags: java, playback, morphia

I have the following function that should return all the _id values from "Agency" collection:

```
public static List<Agency> findByAgencyIds(List<String> ids){
    MorphiaQuery q = Agency.q();
    System.out.println("ids: " + ids);
    q.field("_id").in(ids);    
    return q.asList();
}
```

The following, is the function that uses the previous function

```
public static BasicDBObject getQueryAgenciasMultiples(String agency) {
    List<String> agencyIds = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(agency.split("\\s*,\\s*")));
    List<String> finalList = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (String id : agencyIds) {
        finalList.add(id.trim());
    }
    List<Agency> agencyList = Agency.findByListIds(finalList);

    List<DBRef> dbrefs = new ArrayList();
    agencyList.forEach(a -> dbrefs.add(new DBRef("Agency", a.getId())));                    
    return new BasicDBObject("$in", dbrefs);
}
```

**The problem:**

The query is not retrieving the _id field values from "Agency", since I don't know how to retrieve ObjectId value type from MongoDB.

So, my question is ¿how can I get all _id field values from "Agency" collection?

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance, best regards

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `Query` you can call [`asKeyList()`](http://morphiaorg.github.io/morphia/1.4/javadoc/xyz/morphia/query/QueryResults.html#asKeyList--) on it to get a list of the `Key` instances for the `_id` fields of each entity returned by the query.